# nsdictionary of country names with region titles

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Inside the iphone contacts, when you edit the contact's address a list of country names shows up in a modal view controller.  Is there a way to access this plist of country names from my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. The Contacts app and it's bundled data such as this is accessible only to it, just like every app you might have on an iPhone. Each app is limited to accessing its own data. (There are certainly exceptions to this rule, reserved for Apple's use only. For regular developers, your data is your data and no one can touch it.)

You  will likely have to find or build your own table of countries to include in your app. Luckily, the list of valid countries doesn't change too often (although with world events these days, who knows!).